# Json Schema Reference Property

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

In my json schema file i'm trying to force a reference property, $ref onto the user. However, the following does not work

```
-- sampleSchema.json -- 
{
"definitions": {
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "ref": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
},
"properties": {
    "items" :  {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/items"
    }
}
```

}

The desired output is this where the user must provide a reference path.

```
-- whatever.json -- 
{
    "$schema" :  "sampleSchema.json?reload",
    "items": {
    "$ref": "/myEntityReferenceOfChoice"
        }   
}
```

In in schema file if i leave the $ in , then it doesn't work.  If i take it out for just 'ref' it does.  Can i force the user to supply a $ref?

Im using Visual Studio 2013..

Comment: Can you provide the full schema and data you try to validate? Neither of your quoted examples are valid JSON.

Comment: The schema entire schema is probably overkill so let me attempt to close the gap.

Comment: Sorry, was not finished oviously.

The first quoted section is my schema file that uses the http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema. You can see my defined "items" object property that contains my properites definitions. Within, i'm trying to define that a user my supply a property of type object called "$ref".  However the mere fact that i put the $ in there breaks everything.

The second quoted example is the desired usage scenario. Where the user is providing a "$ref".  If i take the $ out of the equation and just do a 'ref' it works.  If that doesn't clear it up i will put the full example.

Comment: It indeed does not clear things up. Please remind that JSON References are valid within schemas. A full example would be appreciated.

Comment: There are fundamental missing pieces in your schema; for instance, `null` (as in, a JSON null) will validate against it...